# Why CHOOSE FUNCTION nested does not work without apparent visible error in MS Excel?**

Tags: excel, excel-formula, substitution

I have a comments in cell F4 from a data base in HTML and looks like this (in spanish)

```
<b>[2020-02-04 12:15:45]:</b> Se aguarda la llegada de materiales. Hoy llega el material a sitio. Mientras, estamos realizando auditoria en BH715. 
<br>
<b>[2020-01-31 15:16:58]:</b> COMENTARIO ASIGNACION: Se reasigna a otro supervisor por vacaciones.
```

So... I want to clean the text deleting (html tags):
"**" , ":**", "
"

and the result will be:

> [2020-02-04 12:15:45] Se aguarda la llegada de materiales. Hoy llega
>   el material a sitio. Mientras, estamos realizando auditoria en BH715. 
>   [2020-01-31 15:16:58] COMENTARIO ASIGNACION: Se reasigna a otro
>   supervisor por vacaciones.

The two functions nested are using:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(F4;CHOOSE({1\2\3};"<b>";":</b>";"<br>");"")
```

But, only work the first number {1... of the range.
The rest of the number it doesn't work.

official Help here:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-array-constants-in-array-formulas-477443ea-5e71-4242-877d-fcae47454eb8

any advice about that ?
I am using Office 2019/265 the delimiter are semicolons in my case.

thanks a lot.

Comment: will `=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(F4;"<b>";"");":</b>";"");"<br>";"")` work ?

Comment: Thank you very much. 
With "substitute" nested is working. (In fact, I am using in that way), but is curious why it doesnt work using CHOOSE? Because not error appears.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: AFAIK, choose will only return 1 result from the index value.

Comment: Take a look here an example of CHOOSE  "in array" mode.
https://www.lifewire.com/excel-left-lookup-formula-using-vlookup-3124101

Comment: In the link provided.. all choose function + examples is to be coupled with vlookup... None of the example state that choose can be in array mode without vlookup function paired with it. ( :

Comment: Well, the problem (I guess) is not of the "CHOOSE" function.
If not rather the construction of the one matrix that only work in columns or cells, and not in "a single cell" as is my case.

Comment: I guess that pretty much it.. congrats (on resolving it..)